# Trigonometric Identity using sin and csc

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

If $x$ is in the interval $[0, {\pi \over 2}]$ and $y$ is in the interval $[{\pi \over 2}, \pi]$ and $\tan x={4 \over 3}$ and $\csc y={13 \over 5}$, evaluate $$\sin(x+y)$$

The final answer is supposed to be ${-33 \over 65}$

I started by graphing $\csc y={13 \over 5}$ on a Cartesian plane. Because of the cast rule I assume that the triangle will be in quadrant 2 since that is also what the intervals should be for the variable of $y$. I then graph $\sin x$ using the information from $\csc y$.

Here is what I subbed into the equation $$\sin(x+y)$$
$$=\sin x+\sin y$$
$$=\sin x+\csc y$$
$$=\sin x+{5 \over 13}$$
$$={5 \over 13}+{5 \over 13}$$

I obviously didn't do that correctly. Please help!

Comment: I think what you did wrong was directly equate $\sin (x+y) = \sin (x) + \sin (y)$ but in fact $\sin (x+y) = \sin (x) \cos (y) + \cos (x) \sin (y)$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\sin(x+y) \neq \sin(x)+\sin(y)$. It's $\sin(x+y) = \sin(x)\cos(y) + \cos(x)\sin(y)$

Answer (score 0):

As an earlier answer stated, your attempt is wrong since in general we have
$$
\sin(x+y) \neq \sin(x)+\sin(y) \text{ but }\sin(x+y) = \sin(x)\cos(y) + \cos(x)\sin(y)
$$
For the solution we'll need two trigonometric identities
\begin{align}
 \cos ^{2}(\theta )+\sin ^{2}(\theta )=&1 \tag1\\ \tag2
\sin(\theta) =&{\frac {\tan(\theta )}{\sqrt {1+\tan ^{2}(\theta )}}} 
\end{align}
while $(2)$ in this particular form only holds for $\theta \in[0,\pi/2]\cup[3\pi/2,2\pi]$ .

First we compute $\sin(y)$ and $\cos(y)$. We get them from 
$$
\csc(y)=\frac 1 {\sin(y)}=\frac {13}5\iff \sin(y)=\frac 5 {13}
$$
and further we use $(1)$ and get 
$$
\pm\cos(y)=\sqrt{1-\sin(y)^2}=\sqrt{144/169}=12/13
$$
and since we know that $y\in[\pi/2,\pi]$, we also know that $\cos(y)<0$ and therefore we have
$$
\sin(y)=5/13,\; \cos(y)=-12/13
$$
Now we compute $\sin(x)$ by using $(2)$ which gives us
$$
\sin(x) ={\frac {\tan(x)}{\sqrt {1+\tan ^{2}(x )}}}=\frac{4/3}{\sqrt {1+{(4/3)}^{2}}}=\frac 4 5
$$
and again by using $(1)$ and the fact that $x\in[0,\pi/2]$ and hence $\cos(x)>0$ we get 
$$
\cos(y)=\sqrt{1-\sin(y)^2}=\sqrt{9/25}=\frac 3 5
$$
and therefore we have 
$$
\sin(x)=\frac 4 5,\; \cos(x)=\frac 3 5
$$
Eventually we put everything together and get
$$
\sin(x+y) = \sin(x)\cos(y) + \cos(x)\sin(y)=\frac 4 5\cdot \big(-\frac{12}{13}\big)+\frac 3 5 \cdot \frac 5{13}=-\frac {33}{65}
$$
and are done.